# loadFile from a shared folder

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I'm successfully downloading file from a folder "AppFileLIVE" that is shared between friends accessing from my dropbox account:

```
#define dropboxPath @"/xxxx/MyGame/AppFileLIVE"
#define localAppPath [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]

-(void)startDownloads{
    NSString *filename=[[self.fileList objectAtIndex:numberOfFileToDownload] objectForKey:@"filename"];
    NSString *fileInDB=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dropboxPath,filename];
    NSString *fileInApp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",localAppPath,filename];

    [self.restClient loadFile:fileInDB intoPath:fileInApp];
}
```

when I try to access the same file from the app but with another account, the folder is in another directory "/yyyy/blabla/AppFileLIVE"(the account is different!) 
How can I retrive the shared folder indipendently from the account?
thanks

Comment: Have you looked at any dropbox documentation?

Comment: Shared folders can be located at different locations, so if there's a pre-determined shared folder like this that your app needs to access, you'll need a way to determine the right path. One way may be to search for the folder name, but even that can change, so that's also error prone. A better way would be to use the /shared_folders Core API endpoint to look the folder path up by ID in each account: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shared-folders This isn't implemented in the iOS Core SDK though, so you'd have to add it.

Comment: thanks, I didn't found anything and I thought I was searching in the wrong place. So I should implement a recursive search in subfolder till I find the correct folder... but I could have more folders with same names and different path...the link you have posted seems work for Python, Java, PHP and Ruby